# Set timezone for New Zealand

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently developing a website using Laravel. I would like to change the timezone to New Zealand since it will be used there.

```
'timezone' => 'NZ',
```

I currently have that in my config/app.php and it returns the correct time but wrong am/pm.
E.g time returned is 3:03 am, but correct time in new zealand is 3:03 pm.

Comment: that does not look like a valid [timezone for php](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.pacific.php), maybe it is for larvel, but unlikely - how is it set?

Comment: is it not? what's the timezone for new zealand the in php? need help

Comment: `Pacific/Auckland`

Comment: Oh okay. I'll try that

Comment: @Dagon would you like to add that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

valid timezone for php can bee found here: [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

In your case you need NZ so its **Pacific/Auckland**

Why its Auckland and not the capital Wellington i have no idea.

Comment: Why: population. Auckland is over three times larger. The Olson tz database uses the largest city in the time zone, not the capital (which would get contentious in time zones containing multiple countries).

Comment: @duskwuff thanks for the info, as an Aucklander i was not complaining ;-) what do they do when the population size changes?

Comment: Good question. I don't know! The database does support multiple names for zones, though (e.g, `Antarctica/McMurdo` is linked with `Pacific/Auckland`); I imagine they'd make the new largest city a link to the existing name.

Comment: really helpful!

Comment: Also, under Others, there is "NZ"